# TestNG does not see all annotated tests

Tags: annotations, testng, rest-assured, testcase

I have 2 TestNG testcase annotated with `@Test`. A methods have a return type of String, which is as well a testcase. The other one uses the output param of the first. when I ran both test, TestNG only showed that only one ran instead of 2.

```
public class Login {

    private static String INITIATE = "https://login.endpoint.com/initiate";
    private static String COMPLETE = "https://login.endpoint.com/complete";

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test(groups = "middleware", priority = 1)
    public String InitiateLogin() throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();
        request.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("email", "test@test.com");
        json.put("password", "111111");
        request.body(json.toJSONString());
        Response response = request.post(INITIATE);
        String OTP = response.path("OTP");

        if(OTP.matches("[0-9]{4}")) {
            response.then().body(
                    "OTP", equalTo(OTP));
        }
        return OTP;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test(groups = "middleware", priority = 2)
    public void CompleteLogin() throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        RequestSpecification completeRequest = RestAssured.given();
        completeRequest.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        JSONObject completeJson = new JSONObject();
        completeJson.put("Otp", InitiateDeviceRelease());
        completeRequest.body(completeJson.toJSONString());
        Response completeResponse = completeRequest.post(COMPLETE);
        completeResponse.then().body(
                "SessionToken", equalTo("ewrtw4456765v543fw3v"));

    }
}
```

This is the output of the test. It suppose to show that 2 testcases ran, but it obly showed that only one ran. Is it because the first test have a return type and not void? What way can I make testng see that they are 2 testcases?

```
{
    "OTP": "6645"
}
PASSED: CompleteLogin

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Test method cannot have return type, it should be void always.

try changing return type of InitiateLogin() method to void, it should work.

Comment: How do I pass the OTP returned as a response from the first testcase to the second?

Comment: @kehinde You could save it in a field on class level. For example, `private static String savedOtp = null;` then in first method, instead of `return OTP;`, you could do: `savedOtp = OTP`. And this value would be available in other methods of the class. Just might need to add null-check before using it.

Comment: What I did is to write it to a file and read it again. Thanks for the great contribution.

Comment: @kehinde: just curious, any particular reason on file read-write to share the OTP amongst two methods than to use class level private variable as Edvins suggested?

Comment: @gogamote, I think your proposition is right. I may have to change it as suggested. You won bro. Appreciate. I have made the change.